# WordPress Delete User, Preserve Attachments

Tags: wordpress, hook, attachment

When a user is deleted, their posts and attachments are deleted too.

I'd like to prevent the attachments from being deleted.

I've tried to intercept and prevent the post/attachment deletion by using:

```
function prevent_image_deletion($post_id){

    return false;

}

add_action('delete_attachment', 'prevent_image_deletion');
add_action('delete_post', 'prevent_image_deletion');
```

This doesn't seem to be working. After the user is deleted, their image uploads are still being deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you deleting a user?

Comment: I'm using wp_delete_user($userID)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter [`reassign`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user) to your advantage. When a wordpress user is deleted all associated content is either attached to another user or deleted. Upon user deletion you can specify that all content must be assigned to the admin. Try the following:

```
<?php wp_delete_user( $id-of-the-user-to-be-deleted, $id-of-the-user-to-assign-content-too ); ?>
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the data, but not re-assign it?

Comment: You can use `<?php add_action( 'delete_user', 'function_name' ); ?>`and make your custom function to handle the behaviour

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to use the 'delete_attachment' hook instead? Returning false still allows the attachment to be deleted...